# I have 121 columns x 10 rows dataset 1st col -> the index values rest of the col. -> features. I need to smooth the 120 col. against index col. in r

Tags: r, time-series, smoothing, spline

So I am expecting to read the data from the file, perform smoothing using `supsmu`, generate the same time with smoothed data, and write it to a file

how could I do it ?

```r
library(splines)
library(YieldCurve)
library(datawizard)
maturity.SL <- c(0.25, 0.5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10)
Yield.SL <- c(0.0766, 0.0857 , 0.0933, 0.1068, 0.1138, 0.1201, 0.1190, 
              0.1208, 0.1211)
supsmu(maturity.SL, Yield.SL, span="cv")

here my first column = maturity.SL ( index column)
second column = Yield.SL
```

I have another 119 columns in the file

Answer (score 0):

Use the dplyr function 'across' inside a mutate:
Because the function supsmu returns a list instead of a vector, I recommend using an auxiliary function that returns just the smoothed value:

```
set.seed(42)
#dummy data:
yield_df <- data.frame(maturity.SL = c(0.25, 0.5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10),
                 Yield.SL     = c(0.0766, 0.0857 , 0.0933, 0.1068, 0.1138, 0.1201, 0.1190, 0.1208, 0.1211),
                 Yield.SL2    = runif(n = 9, min = 0, max = 0.15),
                 Yield.SL3    = runif(n = 9, min = 0, max = 0.15)
                 )

#auxiliary function
aux_supsmu <- function(x, y){
  result <- supsmu(x, y, span = "cv")
  
  return(result$y)
}

smoothed_df <- 
  yield_df %>% 
  mutate(across(.cols = 2:4, #Select columns from 2 to 4. 
                .fns = ~aux_supsmu(x = maturity.SL, y = .x)))
```

Comment: Thank you very much friend .. will revert back to you